# how to re-enable dbus.service on fedora 36

Tags: linux

In the "Linux Bible, 10th Edition", it claims

> With systemd, some services cannot be disabled. These services are
> static services. Consider the following service, dbus.service:

as it instructs I executed:

```
sudo systemctl disable dbus.service
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dbus-daemon.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/dbus.service.
Removed /etc/systemd/system/messagebus.service.
```

on fedora 36.

I felt something was wrong. I tried to re-enable it.

```
sudo systemctl enable dbus.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file dbus.service does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command to re-enable dbus.service on fedora 36 is:

```
sudo systemctl enable dbus-daemon
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-daemon.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/messagebus.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-daemon.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dbus-daemon.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus-daemon.service.
```

If you have restarted your system, before re-enable it, your system will crash without showing anything. You need to enter into rescue mode to re-enable it.

If your root account doesn't have a password, you can't enter the rescue mode with a error:

> Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.

You can use the methods provided [on this post.](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-cannot-open-access-to-console-the-root-account-is-locked-in-emergency-mode-dracut-emergency-shell/2010)

To set a password to the root account, using the content provided on section "Restoring the bootloader using the Live disk" [on this post.](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/bootloading-with-grub2/#restoring-bootloader-using-live-disk) For fedora 36, I chose the section "For Default Installation in BTRFS", and the instructions worked well.